# Calculate the time complexicity of the recurrence equation

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, recurrence

I'm having problems calculating the complexity of the following recurrence equation.
[image]

It's quite difficult for me to solve it. Could anyone help me to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please confirm whether T(n) is the complexity or you are looking for the complexity of an algorithm that would compute T(n)?

Comment: @Stef T(n) is the recurrence equation of the time complexity of an algorithm. Such as the recurrence equation of the time complexity of [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) is `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n`, then we can get `T(n) = O(nlogn)`.

Answer (score 3):

This is the same recurrence for the average case complexity of quicksort with solution

```
T(n)=O(n log n)
```

[derivation here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Using_recurrences)